# Updating MySQL records based on condition

Tags: php, mysql

DB contains:

```
sku     price   available
0113A5  300     1
0213A5  250     1
```

PHP psuedo-code:

```
['0113A5' => ... , '0313A5' => ... ]

loop:
    if exists in DB ['0113A5']:
        update 
    if not exists in DB ['0113A5']:
        create

delete all other records in the table (in this case 0213A5 which isn't in the array)
```

I can `INSERT` (update) the records with:

```
INSERT INTO product (sku, price, available)
VALUES ('{$sku_safe}', '{$price}', '{$available}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    price = VALUES(price),
    available = VALUES(available)
```

.. but I'm not sure how to delete non-matching records from the table.

Comment: `DELETE FROM product WHERE sku NOT IN ('0113A5', '0313A5', .....)`

Comment: Yes, but issue for me is how do I do it inside the loop, I don't have a simple array to match the `NOT IN`

Comment: Then you should change this to what you have: `['0113A5' => ... , '0313A5' => ... ]`. It looks like a pseudo array to me.

Comment: You don't do it inside the loop, why do you think you need to do it inside the loop? You many not have an array, but you have that initial set of sku values somewhere; or you could build up an array inside the loop as you do the updates/inserts

Comment: @MarkBaker because I'm fetching this huge array from a remote source and iterating over it to only get the stuff I want and populate the db.

Comment: I see, so I should `array_push` each sku and use that array for `NOT IN`

Comment: That's precisely what you should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Approach 1 :** 
For this you must first fetch a recordset of all records present in the table and then check each of those against your array, about whether they are required to be present or not.

**2. Approach 2 :** Put the skus present in the array into a table (Say ValidLookupHelper), and then run a MySql query with a NOT IN that says, found in the original data table but NOT in  the ValidLookupHelper.